# python: can't open file 'help': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to install python packages on my cpanel project. But facing weird issues. Below is cpanel outputs on various commands:

```
[root@host myproject]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr 11 2018, 07:36:10)[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

When I try for command help, get following reponse:

```
[root@host myproject]# python help
python: can't open file 'help': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am trying to install packages from my project directory named 'myproject'. While installing packages I am getting same response:

```
[root@host myproject]# python install requests
python: can't open file 'install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory[root@host myproject]#
```

What I am understanding from error log is python commands are not working/recognized. I have searched for various solutions but could not find any about this issue. Can anybody here help me highlighting what possible mistake I am making? and how this can be solved?

Comment: Can you use `pip install requests` instead of python command.

Comment: First of all, please take a python course and know what you are doing. Second, all of those commands are wrong, for help type `python --help`, to install a module type `pip install package`.

Comment: 1. python --help
2. pip install requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:**

To display command help, you need to run

```
python --help
```

(not `python help`, which instructs python to run a file named `help`)

To install a package, you need to run `pip` (python package manager):

```
pip install your-package-name
```

Comment: how can I install pip for python 2.7 version?

Comment: @SairaNawaz it depends on your operating system, on Windows the Python distribution must already contain pip, on many Linux distros it should work as well. Otherwise, install the `pip` (or probably other name such as `python2-pip`) package with your OS's package manager.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `python help` you are trying to open the file `help`. What you want is calling `python --help`. If you want to install requests you can do `pip install requests`.

Comment: ok , let me check it, for python 2.7 pip is not by default availble for installation so I tried that command